# Milliseconds in a second (short sound waves)

Tags: numbers

When working with short sound waves there are sometimes waves that are **0.23** *milliseconds of a second* and even lower **0.041** *milliseconds of a second*. In seconds they are **0.00023** sec. and **4.1e-5** sec. They are also **230** *microseconds* and **41** *microseconds* of a millisecond.

How do we pronounce these fractions?

> A second has 1000 milliseconds. A millisecond has 1000 microseconds.

Comment: I think that you're a little bit confused here. You can't say 0.23 milliseconds of a second. You can say 0.23 milliseconds, or 0.23 thousandths of a second.

Comment: When you ask "How do we pronounce these fractions?", are you looking for something like "zero-point-zero-four-one milliseconds"? Or are you asking about the "milliseconds of a second" part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of the figures you listed here require "of a second/millisecond".  Because a millisecond and a microsecond are their units of measure, they can stand alone.

You would use "of a second" when refer to expressions of partiality.  For instance, you might say a third of a second.  A thousandth of a second (which is a millisecond, anyways).

You can just use milliseconds/microseconds.